# how i can put two action for a html-python from?(Django)

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I working on a django project which is employee management system. every employee has a card fill with personal information and this is a text box and a dislike button in form, working like that every time manager fill textbox with a number and pressing dislike button and the amount from salary and a SMS going to employee phone number. now I added a like button and i want when employee input a number and pressing like button employee have a increase on salary as given amount. have i can put two action on my form?

view.py

```
class PenaltyEmployee(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.View):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=pk)
        penalty_amount = int(request.POST.get('penalty_amount'))
        employee.salary -= penalty_amount
        employee.save()
        employee_phone_number = employee.phon_number
        api_key ='#'
        url = '#/%s/#' %api_key
        pay_load = {
                'sender' : '#',
                'receptor': employee_phone_number,
                'message': 'penalty'
            }
        res = requests.post(url, data = pay_load)
        return redirect('home')

    def test_func(self):
        return True
```

and this is my list_view.html

```
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'penalty' yaroo.pk %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="number" name="penalty_amount" placeholder="Enter penalty amount">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
          class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path>
          </path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <p> | </p>
<!-- ... this is my like button ... -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
           class="bihand-thumbs-up" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path">
          </path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </form>
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('penalty/<int:pk>/', PenaltyEmployee.as_view(), name='penalty'),  
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html form can have only one action.
you can update it via jquery, or can define multiple forms.
But my suggestion is to handle this in views.

Just give unique name to buttons and
You can find out in views which button is clicked by user

Sample Code:

views.py

```
def post(self, request, pk):
    if request.POST.get("like_btn", None):
        btn = "like_btn"
    else:
        btn = "dislike_btn"
```

html page

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'penalty' yaroo.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" name="penalty_amount" placeholder="Enter penalty amount">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="like_btn">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
        class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path>
        </path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <p> | </p>
<!-- ... this is my like button ... -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="dislike_btn">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
         class="bihand-thumbs-up" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you! the point was that to understand is it possible form can handel more than one action or not! i used your method.